# How to fix Goal Seek and Loops in VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I have a problem with a code. I am making a retirement saving plan for a school project, where I have different inputs. The output table is dependent on the first row in the output table with some changes. I also use goal seek in order to find the first annual saving. However, My code does not work and won't work when I change the inputs... Anyone who can help me?

```vb
Option Explicit

    Sub Savingplan()


    Dim RetAge, crntAge, numSav, fBal, tBase, CapTaxGain
    Dim Inflation, TargBal, CurrSavBal, AnnSav, DivInc
    Dim DivIncRate, CapApprRate, capAppr, yrEndBal
    Dim DivTax, TaxGains, TaxBasis, rowOffset, N



    Sheets("SavingPlan").Select
    Selection.Activate


    RetAge = Cells(15, 2).Value
    crntAge = Cells(14, 2).Value
    numSav = RetAge - crntAge

    Cells(20, 2).Value = numSav

    fBal = "G" & 24 + numSav
    tBase = "H" & 24 + numSav
    TargBal = "B" & 6



    Cells(21, 2).Formula = "=" & TargBal & " *(" & "1" & "+" & "Inflation" & ")^Numsav"
    Cells(22, 2).Formula = "=" & fBal & "-(" & fBal & "-" & _tBase & ")*CapTaxGain - B21"



    Range("B22").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("B19")


    'Compute output table
    Dim SavIncr, rowNum, FirstSav, YrBegBal1, DivInc1, CapAppr1, YrEndBal1,     TaxBas1
    Dim AnnSav1, CappAppr1, TaxBasis1

    FirstSav = Range("B19").Value
    CurrSavBal = Range("B7").Value
    DivIncRate = Range("B10").Value
    CapApprRate = Range("B11").Value
    DivTax = Range("B12").Value
    TaxGains = Range("B13").Value
    SavIncr = Range("B9").Value

    YrBegBal1 = CurrSavBal
    AnnSav1 = FirstSav
    DivInc1 = (YrBegBal1 + AnnSav1) * DivIncRate
    CapAppr1 = (YrBegBal1 + AnnSav1) * CapApprRate
    YrEndBal1 = (YrBegBal1 + AnnSav1 + CapAppr1) + DivInc1 * (1 - DivTax)
    TaxBasis1 = (YrBegBal1 + AnnSav1 + DivInc1) * (1 - DivTax)

    rowOffset = 25
    N = numSav - 1

    Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 2).Value = 1
    Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 3).Value = YrBegBal1
    Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 4).Value = AnnSav1
    Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 5).Value = DivInc1
    Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 6).Value = CapAppr1
    Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 7).Value = YrEndBal1
    Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 8).Value = TaxBasis1


    Dim YrBegBalNew, AnnSavNew, DivIncNew, CapApprNew, YrEndBalNew, TaxBasisNew


    For rowNum = 1 To N

       YrBegBalNew = YrEndBal1
       YrEndBal1 = YrEndBalNew
       AnnSavNew = AnnSav1 * (1 + SavIncr)
       DivIncNew = (YrBegBalNew + AnnSavNew) * DivIncRate
       CapApprNew = (YrBegBalNew + AnnSavNew) * CapApprRate
       YrEndBalNew = (YrBegBalNew + AnnSavNew + CapApprNew) + DivIncNew * (1 - DivTax)
       TaxBasisNew = (TaxBasis1 + AnnSavNew + DivIncNew) * (1 - DivTax)

       YrEndBal1 = YrEndBalNew
       AnnSav1 = AnnSavNew
       TaxBasis1 = TaxBasisNew
       DivInc1 = DivIncNew
       CapAppr1 = CapApprNew

       Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 2).Value = rowNum + 1
       Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 3).Value = YrBegBalNew
       Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 4).Value = AnnSavNew
       Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 5).Value = DivIncNew
       Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 6).Value = CapApprNew
       Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 7).Value = YrEndBalNew
       Cells(rowOffset + rowNum, 8).Value = TaxBasisNew

       YrBegBalNew = YrEndBalNew

    Next rowNum


    End Sub
```

I expect to be able to change the inputs and that the code will function with this.. Also It works one time, but when I run it again it does not work...

Comment: The problem is with the Goal Seek ... Just checked and if I enter the number manually everything works. Any solutions?

Comment: To start, looks like `"=" & TargBal & " *(" & "1" & "+" & "Inflation" & ")^Numsav"` needs to be `"=" & TargBal & " *(" & "1" & "+" & Inflation & ")^" & Numsav` and `"=" & fBal & "-(" & fBal & "-" & _tBase & ")*CapTaxGain - B21"` should be `"=" & fBal & "-(" & fBal & "-" & _tBase & ")*"  & CapTaxGain & " - B21"` . Those values you're assigning in the formula are VBA vars, but you have them IN the quotes which would set them as actual string values, not the numbers within those vba vars.

Comment: The problem is with Goal seek... If I drop the goal seek formula and put a number in there everything works.... Any idea how I can fix the Goal Seek formula?

Comment: After you run your sub, does B22 change to #NAME?

Comment: No... I just get crazy numbers in B19 and B22 is not zero which I ask goal seek to set it to...

Comment: Okay, can you run the sub and copy/paste the exact formula that B22 is from the formula bar after the sub is run?

Comment: =G54-(G54-H54)*CapTaxGain - B21 is the formula in B22.

Comment: Also, when I typed in the formula you sent me it didnt work :(

Comment: I'm not sure for the formatting as I was doing it only in the comment box, but see the `*CapTaxGain` in the formula.  `CapTaxGain` only exists in the VBA code, not in anything that formula should be able to access, indicating the formatting for the .formula is a bit off. `"=" & fBal & "-(" & fBal & "-" & tBase & ")*" & CapTaxGain & " - B21"`